# Is 'stolen' appropriate word?

Tags: word-choice

Somebody took my things without asking me, without my knowledge and didn't return them back to me.

Is 'stolen' word appropriate to represent this situation? (e.g. He stole my things.) If not, what would be the proper word?

**EDIT**: What incident actually took place: In my absence, someone took the duster and marker pens and never returned them back to me. So I was looking for a suitable word. I googled for meaning of stolen, but I felt it wouldn't be proper to say so.

Comment: In the future, please include some research in your question (look up the word you're not sure about, tell us what you've found and why your doubts persist).

Comment: Whether this word is idiomatic depends a lot on context. What did this person take? Do you know who took the item? Are they are stranger or acquaintance?

Comment: Also, please note that ‘return […] back’ is a redundancy; ‘return’ is standard.

Comment: Or, "give ... back".

Comment: @maverick_devil I would probably just say that someone took my pens from the classroom while I was away. This describes that they were stolen without actually calling anyone a thief, which is more diplomatic. At least in the US, being accused of stealing is usually quite offensive to people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically, "stolen" is a suitable word.

---

However, depending on a number of factors, different people may use different words in different situations. Example: [kleptomania](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kleptomania) is also stealing. (to be more precise, the result of kleptomania is stealing)

If confronted, the person might claim that it was a simple **borrowing**, but he did not have a chance to tell you or to return the object - yet.

---

Note: if that happened in an office (in other places also), using this word loudly, especially with several people present, will surely attract a bad energy on you, and it will destroy some of your reputation.

So in this case, it is much better (politically correct) to say: *"took my things without asking me, without my knowledge and didn't return them back to me"* - simply because "to steal" is a very strong word.

Comment: Reputation or not, if someone takes without permission, yes they took the item(s) and it was **stealing**.  It may be a strong word but it is true and accurate.  *Took* can imply with permission.

Comment: @ChrisRogers: did you read the first sentence I wrote? By definition, "take" does not imply permission or denial or anything.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since the dangerous connotations of the term "stealing" may not be apparent to the OP. "Stealing" is a crime, and in many English-speaking countries, false accusations of crime may be considered libelous. One needs to be careful when choosing words in this case.

Comment: The value of what was taken usually determines the the seriousness of the accusation. Accusing someone of stealing an office pen would probably not be taken very seriously unless it was a valuable pen.

Comment: +1 for Virolino's full answer. It would be irresponsible to tell a language learner "yes, go ahead and use 'stolen'" without explaining the possible consequences. The suggested sentence ("took my things without...") is a simple, objective exposition, and allows the listener to draw their own conclusions. To use "stole" is a conclusion, a judgement and an accusation, and needs far more consideration than just relying on a dictionary definition.

Comment: If you're working at Initech and stop by Bill's office and see *your* red stapler on his desk, you don't accuse him of "stealing" or "taking" your stapler -- at least not unless your intent is to burn bridges (and/or the office building). More likely you'd say "Oh hey, there's my stapler! Hey Bill, I'd appreciate it if you'd ask me next time you needed to borrow it... that'd be great."

Comment: @Xerxes: Libel is printed; saying someone stole something (if they didn't) would be slander.

Comment: @terdon: you are right. I had in mind that a kleptomaniac is practically a thief (if he succumbs to the impulse).

Comment: I would likely say "accidentally stolen," which is informal, but alleviates accusation.

Comment: @Phoenix: it is like saying "f*#k you with grease", to alleviate the pain. No matter  how much decorated, "steal" (or any variant of it, e.g. "stolen") is still too strong, and it will burn some bridges.

Comment: @virolino I see what you mean, but in certain informal contexts, I would definitely expect to use it without offense. For perspective, I'm from the US midwest.

Comment: But I suppose that, for an english language learner who isn't completely sure, it wouldn't be advised to use the word "steal".

Answer (score 6):

[Stolen](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stolen) is the past participle of [steal](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/steal) which is:

> to take (the property of another or others) without permission or right, especially secretly or by force.
> *A pickpocket stole his watch.*

So yes, *stolen* is an appropriate word to use when somebody took your things without asking you.

Comment: While you're not wrong, most other dictionaries include a clause relating to return of the item: such as [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/steal), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/steal), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/steal) and the *transitive verb* form in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steal).  Depending on circumstances, there might be the honest intention to return which would make the items 'borrowed without permission'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "stole" or "stolen" means this.

> - to take something without the permission or knowledge of the owner and keep it or use it:
>
> ... He never paid me back, so basically he ended up stealing a hundred dollars from me.

-- [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/steal)

The only exception I can think of would be if it was a person in authority, who was authorized by law to take it.  This would not be considered stealing.

> **The police officer, under orders from a judge,** took my things without asking me, without my knowledge and didn't return them back to me.
>
> **The tax authority** took my things without asking me, without my knowledge and didn't return them back to me.

Comment: I like your alternatives, but in some people's view, taxes and confiscation via court is stealing :-) To my view, even if it is by court order, if the court order or warrant is not presented at the time or prior to taking the items, it is technically still stealing.

Comment: @ChrisR - Even the definition in your answer says, "to take without permission **or right**." There are many exceptions where someone might take something without permission and most would agree that "stealing" is not the most precise term, including: court-ordered confiscation, a parent taking something away from a child, and maybe even someone borrowing something from a close friend or neighbor, depending on the closeness of the relationship. If I wasn't at my desk and a colleague needed a book off my bookshelf, I'd be unlikely to accuse him of "stealing" it, even if he forgot to return it.

Answer (score 3):

To say

> Someone stole my things.

implies that the things were taken intentionally, not by mistake; that the things were taken with the intention of never returning them, but rather with the intent of keeping or selling or disposing of them; and that the things were taken with a malicious or criminal intention, not with any innocent purpose.

That may all be true, but perhaps not all of it is. By saying "stolen" one is taking a hard line, which may cause problems if the things were taken by mistake, or with the intention of returning them, or for some legitimate purpose.

One can soften the word. for example by saying:

> It seems that my things were stolen.

or

> I think that my things may have been stolen. No one asked to borrow them.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in this situation the word 'stolen' is appropriate.